# Google Map APIKey not authorized on Site

Tags: web-services, google-maps-api-3

I face a problem when I use Google Map API to develop a simple Web project. I use the sample codes on the https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={myownAPIkey}&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="map-canvas"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

I deployed the project successfully, but when I access the website a dialog comes out to show some errors.[image: I think I did not type in the wrong APIKey]So the probable problem is that I did not authorize the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site.
**Who can tell me how to authorize it on my site?**